# Basic SQL Feature

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I'm use to doing Django queries through the ORM but the code I'm being given uses all SQL.

I need to be able to get the total amount of all the transactions **summed together** for a particular agent defined within the date range.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
             """
             SELECT a.*, COUNT(t.*) as transactions
             FROM agent a
             JOIN transaction t ON t.agent_id = a.id
             WHERE t.date_created >= %s AND t.date_created < %s and t.status in %s AND a.state = %s
             GROUP BY a.id
             """, [startdate, enddate, config.TX_STATUSES, selectedstate])
    context['agents'] = util.raw_query_dict(cursor)
```

If I was using the Django ORM, I'd use `.aggregate(Sum(...))` and combine that aggregated transaction value to each agent.

Can I do this within the SQL code in anyway?

---

**Update**

I need to actually aggregate the sum of a certain field of the `Transaction` model.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
  source_amount = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
```

Right now, this SQL query that @C14L suggested gives me the total number of transactions that apply to a certain agent between a time frame. I need the total amount of the **source_amount** fields added together which are in the `Transaction` model as illustrated above. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Run from there! It's fine to do raw queries using MyModel.objects.raw() when the same query is hard to write in the ORM but getting a cursor and calling execute Sheesh might as well not use djang at all. Anyway to answer your question. replace that count with sum

Answer (score 0):

Select from your result and sum together all the `transaction` values.

```
SELECT SUM(transactions) AS total FROM (
    SELECT a.*, COUNT(t.*) AS transactions
    FROM agent a
    JOIN transaction t ON t.agent_id = a.id
    WHERE t.date_created >= %s 
      AND t.date_created < %s 
      AND t.status in %s
      AND a.state = %s
    GROUP BY a.id
);
```

---

**Edit:** Not sure if I understood correctly the question you added, but if you just want to sum up the selected `t.source_amount` values, then `SUM()` should be able to do that.

```
SELECT SUM(t.source_amount) AS amount
FROM agent a
JOIN transaction t ON t.agent_id = a.id
WHERE t.date_created >= %s 
  AND t.date_created < %s 
  AND t.status in %s 
  AND a.state = %s
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: would you mind taking a look at the updated question? I have an update to my question. Not sure if this is still possible in SQL.

Comment: Added to my answer.